# How do I run .sql files in a SQL Server database in a transaction rolling back if there are errors in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have been trying to get a system up and running where it will get the content of each `.sql` file it finds in a specified location and run them into a database. So far I have run into the same error time after time:

Exception message:

> Database 'System' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

My code currently looks like this:

```
string ScriptsLocation = "E:\\dashboard\\Scripts";
Server MS_SQL = new Server(Server);
MS_SQL.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
MS_SQL.ConnectionContext.Login = "test";
MS_SQL.ConnectionContext.Password = "test";
MS_SQL.ConnectionContext.DatabaseName = "testDatabase";

string[] Scripts = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(ScriptsLocation);

for (int i = 0; i < Scripts.Length; i++)
{
    ScriptFullName = Scripts[i];

    using (var ScriptText = new StreamReader(ScriptFullName))
    {
        string Query = ScriptText.ToString();

        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(MS_SQL.ConnectionContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            Connection.Open();

            SqlTransaction Transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction();

            SqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
            Command.Transaction = Transaction;

            try
            {
                Command.CommandText = Query;
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried 3 / 4 different ways but I get the same error. If I look at my connection object the `DatabaseName` property reads my specified database name and if I look at my command object the database name in the connection property reads the specified database name so I have no idea where it is getting the database name `System` from.

The user I am using is a sysadmin. I could not find anyone else with this problem online. I have been testing this against SQL Server 2012 and 2008 R2. My SQL script I am testing with is a simple 1 liner UPDATE statement with no USE statements in

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong

```
 string Query = ScriptText.ToString();
```

here you are not passing the content of the file, but the fullname of the class `StreamReader` that is **"System.IO.StreamReader"**, and this is probably the origin of the weird error message where **System** is misunderstood to be the name of the database, **IO** the schema name and **StreamReader** should be the storedprocedure name.

You need to read the content of the file and pass it to your code.

```
string Query = ScriptText.ReadToEnd();
```

However I suggest to use a different approach to run sql scripts.

```
SqlTransaction Transaction = null;
try
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MS_SQL.ConnectionContext.ConnectionString))
    using(Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn)))
    {
       conn.Open();
       using(Transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction())
       {
           string[] Scripts = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(ScriptsLocation);
           for (int i = 0; i < Scripts.Length; i++)
              server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(Scripts[i]);
       }
       Transaction.Commit();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Display error and rollback
    Transaction.Rollback();
}
```